# Google Script Limit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Wanted to know whether there is any limit imposed by Google for script execution, like i am having a Google sheet with lengthy code with having multiple user accessing the sheet. I am having Workspace account and not Consumer account.

Question is, whether there any numbers of execution per day limit imposed by google?

Answer (score 1):

See [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

To improve script performance, see [Apps Script best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).